# Why an irreversible isobaric process won’t satisfy the above given equation in the image above

Tags: thermodynamics

[image]

Here, my doubt is , why is option D incorrect?( the ans  key says A,B,C )...
in isobaric process, the work done is same for both reversible and irreversible processes, then why isnt D correct as well?)

Comment: Welcome to CH SE site! 

Note that using photos/screenshots of text instead of typing text itself is highly discouraged.  The image text content cannot be indexed nor searched for, nor can be reused in answers.  Specifically handwritten scripts can be difficult to decipher.  Consider  copy/pasting or rewriting of at least essential parts. 

Suitable formatting can be done according to [formatting math/chem expressions/equations](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-here).

Comment: Why do you think the term in parenthesis describes the external pressure in an irreversible process?

Comment: That doesn't look like constant pressure for me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In an irreversible process, the equation of state for the gas is not satisfied (due to the presence of viscous stresses).  The equation of state is valid only for thermodynamic equilibrium or for a reversible process.  So use of the VDW equation of state for the pressure is not valid for an irreversible process.